# 17.10 will not boot after Feb 26/2018 update

Tags: boot, updates, 17.10

The laptop keeps flashing the message and will not boot. I tried changing the boot sequence and booting from a flashdrive but recieved the same message 
System bootOrder not found Initializing defaults
Creating boot entry " Boot0003" with label "ubuntu" for file EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi.

Comment: Im havimg the same problem. Have you solved it in mean time?